How to achieve the same performance of Geforce Experience using FFMpeg screen capture
I have a NVidia card and currently use Geforce Experience to do screen capturing. GE performance is really excellent and even if I record a video in 4K, 60 FPS, and high bit rate, I don't experience any performance drop. A video also has full FPS.
Because I need to record audio in 96kHz sample rate not compressed, I run into problems such that GE does not have any option to adjust audio format or sample rate. I guess AAC does not accept anything higher than 48kHz and AAC is the default audio codec. There's no option to change anything in GE settings.
I tried to run FFMpeg, where I can load NVidia codec and adjust codecs but the performance is far from  what I can have using GE. I wonder if such performance is even possible and if yes what settings would you recommend. Currently, I tried the following:
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner `
 -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -video_size 3840x2160 ` -i desktop `
 -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" `
 -map 0:v -map 1:a `
 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 96000 `
 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p6 -tune hq -cq 10 -bufsize 5M `
 -qmin 0 -g 250 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle -temporal-aq 1 -rc-lookahead 30 -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 `
 stream.mkv

Part of the FFMpeg settings has been copied from Using FFmpeg with NVIDIA GPU Hardware Acceleration.
Cheers!
PS. The workaround is to run Geforce Experience and record audio separately via Audacity and Sound Mix and then post-process two channels using FFMpeg, that works but I wonder if I can use pure FFMpeg for that.

Try using ddagrab instead of  gdigrab (requires FFmpeg version above 6.0). You may also try tuning the encoder for speed (in expanse of quality).
